# Variable in HTML drop down menu

Tags: html, tcl

i need to create an HTML drop down menu with option variable based on external list.

i'm tryng with:

```
set item_list [$var]
<select> 
<option value="$item_list">$item_list</option> 
<option value="$item_list">$item_list</option> 
<option value="$item_list">$item_list</option> 
<option value="$item_list">$item_list</option> 
<option value="$item_list">$item_list</option> 
</select>
```

but what i obtain is all option in this way

```
{volvo saab opel audi}
```

Any suggest?

Comment: Presumably you're using something more than just HTML here?

Comment: Yes, is a part of tcl work

Comment: I'm not familiar with tcl (and you should probably include information about that in the question and tags), but it sounds like what you're looking for is basically how to loop over your list of values and output an `<option>` element for each value in that loop.

Comment: You will need to supply a lot more context in order to get useful help.  There are many ways of generating and processing html with Tcl.  See https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/html and https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Category+Webserver for some of the possibilities.  You need to tell us which specific tools you are using, there are just too many possibilities to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually creating the HTML code is one option:

```
set item_list {volvo saab opel audi}
set html_code "<select>"

foreach item $item_list {
    append html_code "<option value=\"$item\">$item</option>"
}

append html_code "</select>"

puts $html_code
```

However, there are other template processing packages described [here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Template+and+Macro+processing). Since you didn't describe your use case in greater detail, this should suffice.

Comment: Using a templating scheme is recommended so that necessary quoting is easier to insert. There isn't much needed in this example... but as soon as things get more like production it becomes mandatory to take proper care.